# Structure of the cosets of the finite group

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $H,K$ are subgroups such that
$$K < H < G.$$
Is there a relation between $H$-cosets and $K$-cosets? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Each $K$-coset is contained in one $H$-coset, so if you think of the cosets as partitions of the set $G$, then the $K$-cosets are a refinement of the $H$-cosets, as partitions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But it turns out that $H$-cosets can be obtained by taking unions of the $K$-cosets in $G$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ can partition $H$ and $H$ can partition $G$.

Thus the number of $K$-cosets is a multiple of the number of $H$-cosets.

Comment: To complement, $[G:K] = [G:H]\times [H:K]$.